# Angular 7 installing bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-cli

I'm following the "Pro Angular 6" book which should work with Angular 7. I start the project like so;

Install angular cli

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

NOTE: This installed version 7.3.0 of the cli tool

Now install the TODO app

```
ng new todo
cd todo
ng serve --port 3001 --open
```

This works, then I add in bootstrap

```
npm install bootstrap@4.1.1
```

And I add the following to styles

```
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],
```

Now when I serve the project I get the following error;

```
$ ng serve --port 3001 --open
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:3001, open your browser on http://localhost:3001/ **

Date: 2019-02-04T00:42:38.279Z
Hash: 3b3bf9a4d6733eee0b6c
Time: 5466ms
chunk {es2015-polyfills} es2015-polyfills.js, es2015-polyfills.js.map (es2015-polyfills) 5.07 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 1.88 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 2.09 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 1.03 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 327 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/es2015-polyfills.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6/array' in '/home/map7/code/pro_angular_6/chap2_prep/todo/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/es2015-polyfills.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6/date' in '/home/map7/code/pro_angular_6/chap2_prep/todo/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/es2015-polyfills.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6/function' in '/home/map7/code/pro_angular_6/chap2_prep/todo/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/es2015-polyfills.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6/map' in '/home/map7/code/pro_angular_6/chap2_prep/todo/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/es2015-polyfills.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6/math' in '/home/map7/code/pro_angular_6/chap2_prep/todo/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/es2015-polyfills.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6/number' in '/home/map7/code/pro_angular_6/chap2_prep/todo/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/es2015-polyfills.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6/object' in '/home/map7/code/pro_angular_6/chap2_prep/todo/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/es2015-polyfills.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6/parse-float' in '/home/map7/code/pro_angular_6/chap2_prep/todo/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/es2015-polyfills.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6/parse-int' in '/home/map7/code/pro_angular_6/chap2_prep/todo/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/es2015-jit-polyfills.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6/reflect' in '/home/map7/code/pro_angular_6/chap2_prep/todo/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/es2015-polyfills.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6/regexp' in '/home/map7/code/pro_angular_6/chap2_prep/todo/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/es2015-polyfills.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6/set' in '/home/map7/code/pro_angular_6/chap2_prep/todo/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/es2015-polyfills.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6/string' in '/home/map7/code/pro_angular_6/chap2_prep/todo/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/es2015-polyfills.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6/symbol' in '/home/map7/code/pro_angular_6/chap2_prep/todo/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/es2015-polyfills.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es6/weak-map' in '/home/map7/code/pro_angular_6/chap2_prep/todo/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/jit-polyfills.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es7/reflect' in '/home/map7/code/pro_angular_6/chap2_prep/todo/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models'
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/common/src/location/location.d.ts(8,34): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts(9,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(8,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/event_emitter.d.ts(8,39): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/query_list.d.ts(8,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/util/lang.d.ts(8,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
src/app/app.component.ts(3,1): error TS2354: This syntax requires an imported helper but module 'tslib' cannot be found.

ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: I've tried to replicate the issue, but everything seems to be working. Did it compile when removing the bootstrap css?  I tried using: Angular CLI: 7.3.0
Node: 8.11.3
OS: win32 x64
bootstrap: ^4.1.1 
Added syles: node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: I just removed node_modules and did a 'npm install', then it all came to life. Not sure why that would changing things I thought the ng new would of done a npm install

Comment: Make sure you have @angular-devkit/build-angular as a dev dependency.

Comment: @RamChandraNeupane  you are correct  @angular-devkit/build-angular is missing

Comment: @Dexter Great i'm posting answer here for if someone ran into same issue

Answer (score 2):

I believe yo need to install `@angular-devkit/build-angular` as a `dev dependencies` in order to solve this issue

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `--save` during the installation so that angular will add this dependency inside the package.json. try below code.

`npm install bootstrap@4.1.1 --save`

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Add Bootstrap to package.json

```
npm install bootstrap --save
npm install jquery --save
npm install popper.js
```

Add the following lines to the “dependencies” section of the apps’ package.json file

```
    "dependencies": {
  ..
  "jquery": "^3.3.1",
  "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
  "popper.js": "^1.14.3"
}
```

> 2. Add Bootstrap to angular.json

```
"apps": [{
  ...,
  "styles": [
     "styles.css".
     "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
     "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
     "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
}]
```

> 3. Finally, add Bootstrap to the app module

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import bootstrap from "bootstrap";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```